# opencart Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: arguments, opencart

I installed opencart in my server hosting. But the site shows the lines given below.
My site is http://fruitsclubbd.com/

Is it problem of server or opencart?

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home8/fruitscl/public_html/index.php on line 52
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home8/fruitscl/public_html/index.php on line 61
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home8/fruitscl/public_html/index.php on line 61
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home8/fruitscl/public_html/index.php on line 69

Here is the lines of index.php form line 40 to 70.

// Application Classes

require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/customer.php');

require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/affiliate.php');

require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/currency.php');

require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/tax.php');

require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/weight.php');

require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/length.php');

require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/cart.php');

// Registry

$registry = new Registry();

// Loader

$loader = new Loader($registry);

$registry->set('load', $loader);

Comment: Did you check the code in the mentioned lines?

Comment: Please, update Your question with the code from `index.php` starting at line 40 and ending at line 70. We cannot provide any help without knowing what may cause it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to use `mysqli`? If so, edit both of your config files on the `DB_DRIVER` line and change it from `mysql` to `mysqli`. All what probably happened was choosing *mysqli* instead of *mysql* during the installation.

Comment: I already have mysqli in config.php i.e define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');

Comment: You need to change it to ('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');